# CSS :hover wont work if there's an absolute div behind it?

Tags: html, css

```css
footer {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #121212;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#copyright {
  margin-left: 3%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#icon {
  background-image: url('../img/icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 85px;
  height: 86px;
  opacity: 0.050;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#top {
  background-image: url('../img/backtop.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  margin-top: 4%; 
  margin-right: 6%;
  float: right;
}

#top:hover {
  background-image: url('../img/tophover.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px; 
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="top"></div>
  <span id="copyright" class="left_content">GGLex is copyrighted &copy 2014, All rights reserved.</span>
  <div id="icon"></div>
</footer>
```

What it looks like:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/08f0742032b0111354d985e158d2b9f5.png))</sub>

I am trying to add a faded out icon, on the right side on my footer. I did it, works just fine, but when I tried to add back to top button with hover, it failed.

Basically, when I hover, it won't work, but if I remove the div "icon", it will work easily (the hover).

Why does it happen & how can I make it work?

Comment: A fiddle would be nice. :)

Comment: Try increasing the z-index of the element you are setting `hover` on.

Comment: @user3123545 check my answer to see if it helps

Comment: what is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/us6uS/10/

Comment: @web-tiki Well thats my question..

Comment: @user3123545 I mean in the fiddle I linked, the image changes on hover so what is the issue you are facing meaning what do you want to achieve?

Comment: When the icon overlapping the transparent logo, see the screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this happens sometimes when css styles overlaps. You can use javascript to solve this...

```
onmouseover="window.location='URL HERE'"
Example
<div onmouseover="window.location='URL HERE'"></div>
```

Hope this helps and please comment back if this doesn't work or you need more help

the below works...

```
 <footer>
 <div id="top"></div>
 <span id="copyright" class="left_content">GGLex is copyrighted &copy 2014, All rights reserved.</span>
 <div id="icon" onmouseover="window.location='URL HERE'"></div>
 </footer>
```

URL TO top of page. ID any element at top of page for example id="top" then replace URL with  www.YOUR_WEB_NAME.CO.UK/#top

Comment: I prefer a proper CSS fix, but if nothing works, ill use this. Thanks.

Comment: have you tested it out

Comment: @user3123545 are you using HTML and CSS only

Comment: @user3123545 Hello, in your case I think it is not possible to use CSS and HTML only. However, if there is a way I am very curious to find out what it is.

Comment: Also, tried it, doesn't work + I also tried jquery .hover() method, doesn't work aswell, only works when I remove <div id="icon...

Comment: @user3123545 I am very curious to find a solution

Comment: I can put the logo into footer background in photoshop, but that's a cheap fix :/

Comment: @user3123545 I understand where you are coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `pointer-events: none;` to the absolutely positioned element. That way clicks/"pointer events" can go "through it", affecting the element behind it.